# Store large Json in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a large Json file say 100 MB - 300 MB , but what I understand is Cosmos DB only supports 2MB item size, if that is the case what is the alternative . How can I save my JSON and query over it. Basically my Json is unstructured and Cosmos would be perfect choice for me . But due to size limitation I am unable to proceed.

Comment: You haven't shared any schema, sample data, etc so it's a bit difficult to even think about a solution, but... I doubt you're going to find any document store that allows for such size documents (e.g. MongoDB  & AWS DocumentDB are limited to 16MB docs). Even being unstructured, you'll need to rethink your schema. For example: do you have unbounded arrays of data (meaning you can just store an unlimited amount of data within an array)? If so, this is a great area to refactor, moving array elements into separate documents. Aside from that... this really is too broad, as written, and off-topic.

Comment: And if you truly need to store content of hundreds of MB, consider something like blob storage - store your large content there, and use Cosmos DB to store only the properties you'll require for searching/indexing, along with a uri to your larger document.

Comment: I do have my Json files in Blob storage and I pick these files to CosmosDB to query.

Comment: At this point, I'd suggest rethinking your schema, since you won't find any way of storing hundreds of MB within a single document. Think about  the metadata required for searching. If you really need hundreds of MB, consider storing separate documents for large content within an array. Outside of arrays, I can't imagine how you're getting such large documents (unless you're storing massive amounts of text; in that case, I'd suggest moving the text to blobs, and indexing that text with Azure Search or something similar. But again, you haven't shared any schema here so... this is all guessing.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use Cosmos DB, you'd need to transform the items into a smaller representation with more reasonably sized items under the 2 MB limit.

If that's not possible, consider using something like Azure Cognitive Search to [index your JSON files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-json-blobs) from blob storage.